# mvc 4 application deployment error method not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

Every thing is working fine on my local machine but getting error on live server IIS 7.5

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.GetUnvalidatedCollections(System.Web.HttpContext,
>   System.Func`1<System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection>
>   ByRef,
>   System.Func`1
>   ByRef)'.

Comment: Post code here to rectify issue

Comment: Dll missing on dev machine? Or reference in Web.config?

Comment: If I removed the parameter then login page will be display but with parameters its showing error public ActionResult LogOn(string ReturnUrl)
        {
            User _user = new User();
            _user.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl; 
            _user.ErrorMessage = "";
            return View(_user);
        }

Comment: already added all the dependencies like              
    System.Web.Mvc
    Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
    System.Web.Razor
    System.Web.WebPages
    System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Answer (score 1):

MVC4 is not part of Windows Server 2008 R2.
You need to localcopy all MVC4 assemblies.

```
System.Web.Mvc.dll 
System.Web.Razor.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll     

System.Web.Extensions.dll 
System.Web.Helpers.dll

Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
Microsoft.Web.Http.dll
Microsoft.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
Microsoft.Web.Http.Tracing.dll
Microsoft.Web.Http.OData.dll
Microsoft.Data.OData.dll

System.Web.Optimization.dll
System.Web.Providers.dll

System.Net.Http.Formatting
System.Spatial.dll
Antlr3.Runtime.dll
```

**Edit:**
Are you using a developer preview version of one or all dlls on your development computer, and have you installed the MVC framework on the server ?
If yes, the GAC version of the dll would take preference over the bin-deployed version.

Try MVC-Diagnostics:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/05/asp-net-mvc-diagnostics-using-nuget.aspx

Comment: you means to copy all the dll's manually from local and paste in bin directory and then re-publish it

Comment: @angrej.gill: You can just copy them to the bin directory. Also make sure you use the right .NET framework (4 vs 4.5, is 4.5 installed ? Does the application pool use the right framework ? )

Comment: this is my diagnostic report Operating system: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
.NET Framework version: 4.0.30319.269 (64-bit)
Web server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Integrated pipeline: True
Worker process: w3wp.exe
AppDomain: Homogenous = True, FullTrust = True

Comment: I need this to solve on urgent basis friends help me     http://lifeconnected.logicerp.com/Account/LogOn you can check error here

Comment: @angrej.gill: Try MVC-Diagnostics.